# Prove that if $(X,⊥)$ is abelian then for any permutation $σ$ the equality $x_{σ(1)}⊥...⊥x_{σ(n)}=x_1⊥...⊥x_n$ holds.

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, permutations, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups

If $M$ and $N$ are a set then for pratical reason let's we put
$$
\mathcal F(N,M):=M^N
$$

Now if $(X,\bot)$ a [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) then by the [recursion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#The_recursion_theorem) it is not hard to prove (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2459739/736008) for details) the existence of sequence $(\bot^n)_{n\in\omega_+}$ into $\bigcup_{n\in\omega_+}\mathcal F(X^n,X)$ such that $\bot^n$ is in $\mathcal F(X^n,X)$ and such that for any $x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1}$ in $\omega_+$ in $X$ with $n$ in $\omega_+$ the equality
$$
\tag{0}\label{0}\bot^{n+1}(x_1,\dots , x_n, x_{n+1})=\big(\bot^n(x_1,\dots , x_n)\big)\bot x_{n+1}
$$
holds; moreover, it is possibile to prove that $\bot^2$ is just $\bot$ and for any $x_1,\dots, x_m,x_{m+1},\dots,x_{m+n}$ in $X$ with $m$ and $n$ in $\omega_+$ the equality
$$
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{1}
\bot^{m+n}(x_1,\dots,x_m,x_{m+1},\dots x_{m+n}) = \big(\bot^m(x_1, \ldots, x_m)\big) \bot\big(\bot^n(x_{m+1}, \ldots, x_{m+n})\big)
\end{equation}
$$

So, by this it is possibile to put
$$
x_1\bot\dots\bot x_n:=\bot^n(x_1,\dots, x_n)
$$
for any $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $X$ with $n$ in $\omega_+$ so that let's we prove that for any permutations $\sigma$ of $\{1,\dots, n\}$ then the equality
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}x_{\sigma(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\sigma(n)}=x_1\bot\dots\bot x_n
$$
provided that $(X,\bot)$ is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

First of all let be $\lambda$ the permutation which works as $\sigma$ except for $\sigma^{-1}(n+1)$ and for $n$ whereas let be $\tau$ the permutation with interchange only $\sigma^{-1}(n+1)$ with $n$ and vice versa: in matrix notation we can represent $\lambda$ with the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)-1\big) & \sigma^{-1}(n+1) & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)+1\big) & \dots & n & n+1\\
\sigma(1) & \dots & \sigma\big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)-1\big) & \sigma^{-1}(n+1) & \sigma\big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)+1\big) & \dots & \sigma(n) & n+1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whereas we can represent $\tau$ with the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)-1\big) & \sigma^{-1}(n+1) & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)+1\big) & \dots & n & n+1\\
1 & \dots & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)-1\big) & n+1 & \big(\sigma^{-1}(n+1)+1\big) & \dots & n & \sigma^{-1}(n+1)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, observing that $\sigma$ is just the composition $\tau\circ\lambda$ and observed that $\lambda$ does not changes the $n+1$-th element and $\tau$ does not changes the first element, let's we assume that \eqref{2} holds for any $n$ so that by associativity we observe that
$$
x_{\sigma(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\sigma(n)}\bot x_{\sigma(n+1)}=x_{\tau(\lambda(1))}\bot\dots\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n))}\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n+1))}=\\
x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n))}\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n+1))}=
x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\Big(x_{\tau(\lambda(2))}\bot\dots\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n))}\bot x_{\tau(\lambda(n+1))}\Big)=\\
x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\Big(x_{\lambda(2)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\lambda(n)}\bot x_{\lambda(n+1)}\Big)= x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\lambda(n)}\bot x_{\lambda(n+1)}=\\
x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\lambda(n)}\bot x_{n+1}=\Big(x_{\lambda(1)}\bot\dots\bot x_{\lambda(n)}\Big)\bot x_{n+1}=\\
\Big(x_{1}\bot\dots\bot x_{n}\Big)\bot x_{n+1}=x_{1}\bot\dots\bot x_{n}\bot x_{n+1}
$$
which proves that it holds for $n+1$; moreover commutativity implies that \eqref{2} holds for $n$ equal to $2$: so by induction we conclude that \eqref{2} holds for any $n$ in $\omega_+$ bigger than $2$.

So, I would like to know if \eqref{2} holds and so if I well proved it. Moreover, as you can see, I used associativity not only to prove \eqref{2} but also to define $\bot^n$ with $n$ in $\omega_+$ which actually let to make sense to any string $x_1\bot\dots\bot x_n$ with $x_1,\dots ,x_n$ in $X$ and with $n$ in $\omega_+$: so I ask if the result can hold even without associativity. Could someone help me, please?

Comment: I think that using the fact that any permutation is a composition of transpositions might be simpler.

Comment: @Zag Since I studied permutations in Linear Algebra, me too initially I thought to use this but unfortunately I was not able: anyway now I am starting to study Abstract Algebra so that I would like to do not use transpositions explicitly

Comment: (2) does hold, and I think your proof is probably correct - you've certainly understood the key trick in the induction step, so well done. Associativity is necessary in a strong sense - any operation with this "generalised commutativity" property is associative, as $(ab)c = (bc)a = a(bc)$. The notation in your proof is a bit funny, I think - I'm not sure writing things like $\bigcup_{n \in \omega_+} \mathcal F(N, M)$ and quoting the recursion theorem is really making anything any clearer.

Comment: @IzaakvanDogen Okay, so associativity is necessary. However, I suspect that the statement can bit generalised: indeed, it seems to me that if $x_1,\dots, x_n$ are simply commutable with respect $\bot$ then the equality (2) holds without supposing that $\bot$ is completely abelian and the proof can be done as above simply proving by **finite** induction that the set $$S_n:=\{m\in S(n):x_{i(0)}\dots x_{i(m)}=x_{i(\sigma(0))}\dots x_{i(\sigma(m))}\text{with }i(0),\dots, i(m)\in S(n)\text{ and with }\sigma\in\mathfrak S_m\}$$ is equal to $S(n)/1$. So what do you think about?